# C++ Average scores using file IO and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io

I'm currently working on a project where I have to read information in from a file:
`123456789 77.2 88.3 22 28 35 45 33 35 40
234567890 97.5 90 25 30 38 48 34 35 50
345678901 82.4 77.5 22.5 27 35.5 44 35 33 48`
and placed into arrays and displayed. The information above is the StudentID, test scores (2), and homework scores (7). The problem I think I've run into is my set of code trying to obtain the average of these scores:

`students[i].hwAve = students[i].hwAve / 7;                                    students[i].testAve = students[i].testAve / 2;
students[i].finalScore = (students[i].hwAve * 0.40) + (students[i].testAve * 0.60);`

But I'm not positive. Below is my full code. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct SStudent
{
    int studentID;
    double test[2];
    double hw[7];
    double hwAve = 0;
    double testAve = 0;
    double finalScore;
    char grade;
};

int getInput(SStudent[], int);
void process(SStudent[], int);
void display(const SStudent[], int size);

int main()
{
    int totStudents;
    int i;
    SStudent amount[30];

    totStudents = (amount, 30);
    process(amount, totStudents);
    display(amount, totStudents);

    _getch();
};

int getInput(SStudent students[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream scores;
    scores.open("scores.txt");

    if (!scores)
    {
        cout << "Can't open input file.\n";
        _getch();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scores >> students[i].studentID;

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            scores >> students[i].test[j];

        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
            scores >> students[i].hw[k];

        if (!scores) break;
    }
    return i;
}

void process(SStudent students[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            students[i].testAve += students[i].test[j];

        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
            students[i].hwAve += students[i].hw[k];

        students[i].hwAve = students[i].hwAve / 265;
        students[i].testAve = students[i].testAve / 200;
        students[i].finalScore = (students[i].hwAve * 0.40) + (students[i].testAve * 0.60);

        if (students[i].finalScore < 60)
            students[i].grade = 'E';

        else if (students[i].finalScore > 60 && students[i].grade <= 69)
            students[i].grade = 'D';

        else if (students[i].finalScore > 69 && students[i].grade <= 79)
            students[i].grade = 'C';

        else if (students[i].finalScore > 79 && students[i].grade <= 89)
            students[i].grade = 'B';

        else
            students[i].grade = 'A';
    }
}

void display(const SStudent students[], int size)
{
    ofstream grades;
    grades.open("grades.txt");
    grades << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    grades << "STUDENT ID\t\tHW AVE\t\tTEST AVE\t\tFINAL SCORE\t\tGRADE" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << students[i].studentID << "\t" << students[i].hwAve << "\t\t << students[i].testAve << "\t\t" << students[i].finalScore << "\t\t" <<     students[i].grade << endl;


    if (grades)
        cout << "Output file created.";
    else
        cout << "Output file not created.";
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to calculate an [average](https://www.mathsisfun.com/mean.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to calculate an average, and the display the student ID, average test grade, average homework grade, their overall grade, and the letter grade corresponding. @fetherolfjd

Comment: I provided that link as an indirect way of questioning why you're dividing these numbers by 265 and 200... I don't see how you'll calculate an average by doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include that the max amount of points earned over the 7 homework assignments adds up to be 265. "There are seven homework assignments, with maximum points of 25, 30, 40, 50, 35, 35 and 50 respectively"

Comment: You _really_ need to visit [this link about how to calculate averages.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/average.html)

Comment: I really feel like an idiot now..